# Knockout.js Custom Binding "Update Function is Not called "

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have below custom binding,Its star rating, On page load for me init and update is called but after that, Only init function is called not the update function. I need update function in which have class "Chosen" toggleclass,which add class to star binding after selected. I am facing problem in that kindly suggest.

```
    <div data-role=view id="view1">
    <div id="divstarRating" data-bind="click:selectStar">
    <span id="Star" data-bind="readonlyStarRating:starpoints"> </span>
    </div>
    </div>
.starRating span {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url(../star.png);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: -24px 0;
 }

 .starRating span.chosen {
  background-position: 0 0;
 } 

 .starRating:hover span {
 background-position: -24px 0;  
transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
}

.starRating:hover span.hoverChosen {
 background-position: 0 0;
 transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  }

   function StarViewModel() {
    self.starpoints= ko.observable();

    self.selectStar=function(){
    window.location.href="view1"
     //here i get selected star value
      starValue=self.starpoints()

      //here i am using ajax to post star value
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: Model,
                url: serverUrl + 'xxx/xx/xx',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loading-image').hide();
                  // after susccees of post success ajax data consist of star rating value
                   self.starpoints= ko.observable(data);
                },
      }
   }

    $(document).ready(function () {
     ko.bindingHandlers.readonlyStarRating =
 {
 init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
 $(element).addClass("readonlyStarRating");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 $("<span>").appendTo(element);
         $("span", element).each(function (index) {
         var observable = valueAccessor();
         $(this).hover(
             function () { 
 $(this).prevAll().add(this).addClass("hoverChosen") },
             function () { 
 $(this).prevAll().add(this).removeClass("hoverChosen") }
         )
      });
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
     var observable = valueAccessor();
     $("span", element).each(function (index) {
     $(this).toggleClass("chosen", index < observable());
     });
    }
  }
    ViewModel = new StarViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
  });
```

Comment: The update code looks fine. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle. The update part of the binding is working as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/9do8aoeb/

Comment: @thanks for your time, but its didnt work for me, i have 2 views ,In 1st view i have binding handlers and in  second view i have  <div id="divstarRating">
        <span id="Star" data-bind="readonlyStarRating:starpoints"> </span>
       </div>,at first time it hits the update function but after selecting the start  rating,I am redirected to 1st view,after again come back 2nd view,update wont call or update function wont get called when i click the increment or decrement, i dont know why update is not working second time

Comment: Show your javascript

Comment: @i have update my code,my issue is the update function have toggle chosen class,so i need to change all time when user select the satr rating

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that is updating the starpoints observable. There's nothing setting its value so I'm not sure when you expect the update function to execute.

Comment: @ when i navigate  first time to  view1 ,when i select the start rating the variable starpoints will get that value and Update function will working.But when i go for second time to View1,the if i select the star rating the i get the selected value in starpoints but its not hit update function

Comment: In  above code on ajax sucess i am passing data to   self.starpoints= ko.observable(data); need this value for further operation

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kittysarvaj/y6dg1vzk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your jsFiddle, in your `okay()` function:

```
self.okay = function ()
{
    data = self.UserFeedpoint
    self.UserFeedpoints = ko.observable(data);
    window.location.href = "#home1"
}
```

You're overwriting the observable that the UI is bound to with a new observable. You just need to change it to update the existing observable instead. like:

```
self.okay = function ()
{
    data = self.UserFeedpoint
    self.UserFeedpoints(data);
    window.location.href = "#home1"
}
```

Comment: its working but, i am unable to clear the self.UserFeedpoints(data); value

Comment: can u please help me with one of my other question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179984/how-to-carry-the-data-from-one-viewmodel-to-another-viewmodel-knockout-js"

Comment: @kittysarvaj I'll take a look