# Change class for a div in the list using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am binding list of data few of which have image. I need to change the classes of div if the image value is NULL.

When image value is NULL, I need to change div classes Like, Delete,listcheckbox to ILike, Idelete, Ilistcheckbox or vice-versa.

How can I do it?

```
  <div data-role=view id="userProfile">
   <ul class="oneClass"  data-role="listview" id="Feeds-listview" data-bind="foreach:data">
   <li style="background-color:#FFF;white-space:normal">
  <div style="width:100%">
        <div data-bind="visible:ImageUrl">
     <img style="height: 200px;width: 300px;margin-top: 10px;" data-bind="attr: { src:ImageUrl }" />
    </div>

     <div data-bind="click:$root.Like" class="Like" >
 <div data-bind="click:$root.delete" class="delete"> </div> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="listcheckbox "/>
  </div>


    </li>
    </ul>
    <div>

 <style>
  .Like{
   }
  .delete{
   }
  .listcheckbox{
   }
  .ILike{
    }
  .Idelete{
  }
 .Ilistcheckbox{
   }

  </style>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of either `css` or `style` bindings. The css binding adds or removes one or more named CSS classes to the associated DOM element based on an expression. So, you can check if the expression for the `ImageUrl` is **truthy** or **falsy** and then apply the css accordingly.

**Change code from**

```
<div data-bind="click:$root.Like" class="Like" >
 <div data-bind="click:$root.delete" class="delete"> </div>
```

**To**

```
<div data-bind="click:$root.Like, css: { Like: ImageUrl }" >
 <div data-bind="click:$root.delete, css: { delete: ImageUrl }"> </div>
```

Working Code sample

```js
 var viewModel = {
        ImageUrl : null,
        ImageUrlNotEmpty : "value"
    };
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.Like{
background-color: yellow;
   }
  .delete{
  background-color: green;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


    <div data-bind="css: { Like: ImageUrl }" >ImageUrl is empty Div 1</div> 
 <div data-bind="css: { delete: ImageUrl }">ImageUrl is empty Div 2</div> 
 
   <div data-bind="css: { Like: ImageUrlNotEmpty }" >ImageUrl is NOT empty Div 3</div> 
 <div data-bind="css: { delete: ImageUrlNotEmpty }">ImageUrl is NOT empty Div 4</div>
```

Comment: glad, it helped :)

Comment: Agalo.....If possible, can you help us with another question.    

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179984/how-to-carry-the-data-from-one-viewmodel-to-another-viewmodel-knockout-js%22