# How to carry one viewModel data to other ViewModel function using Knockout JS of another page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I am using the Knockout js in my single page Application,I need to carry the value of one viewmodel data to another viewModel data,So i can reduce my duplication creating same view, How i can achieve this below is my code.I got 2 different js file,which one consist of Employee ViewModel and in another Department View Model

```
      //Employee View
       <div class="Employee-view"  data-role="view" id="employee">
         <div data-role="content" >
           <ul>
             <li foreach:EmployeeData>
              //Onlcick of this need to navigate to  Department view and bind all values on particular Employee ID 
              <div databind:"click:GetDepartmentDetails">
                <span data-bind:"text:EmployeeId"> <span>
                <span data-bind:"text:EmployeeName"> <span>
                <span data-bind:"text:EmployeeImage"> <span>
             <div> 
            <li>
          <ul>
        </div>
       </div>


     EmployeeViewModel = new EmployeeDetailsViewModel();;
     $(".Employee-view").each(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(EmployeeViewModel, $(this).get(0));
     });


     function EmployeeViewModel(){
        var self=this;
        self.EmployeeData = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.GetEmployee = function(UserName,Password){  
           var UserModel = { UserName: UserName, Password: Password}
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: serverUrl + 'xxx/xxx/GetEmployee',
                data: UserModel,
                success: function (data) {
                   self.EmployeeData($.map(data, function (item) {
                     return new EmployeeModel(item);
                   }))
                }
           });
         }

        //Click EVENT
        self.GetDepartmentDetails=(EmployeeData){
          // I am getting all the value in this ViewModel,I need to pass   this value to DepartmentViewModel  and i need to call the function  
          self.GetEmployeeByDepartment();
        }

     }

     function EmployeeModel(data)
     {
       var self = this;
       self.EmployeeId = ko.observable(data.EmployeeId)
       self.EmployeeName = ko.observable(data.EmployeeName)
       self.EmployeeImage = ko.observable(data.EmployeeImage)
      }

       //Department View
       <div class="Department-view" data-role="view" id="Department">
         <div data-role="content">
           <ul>
             <li   data-bind:"foreach:DepartmentData ">
              <div>
                <span data-bind:"text:DeptId"> <span>
                <span data-bind:"text:DeptName"> <span>
              </div> 
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>

      //Department View Model
      function DepartmentViewModel ()
      {
        var self = this;
        self.DepartmentData = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.GetEmployeeByDepartment = function(item){  
          employeeID = item.EmployeeId
          employeename = item.Employeename
          var DeptModel = { Employeename: employeeID, Employeename: employeename}
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: serverUrl + 'xxx/xxx/GetDepratmenDetails',
            data: DeptModel ,
            success: function (data) {
               self.DepartmentData ($.map(data, function (item) {
                 return new DepartmentModel(item);
               })),
            });
          }}
       }

       function DepartmentModel(data)
       {
         var self=this;
         self.DeptId = ko.observable(data.DeptID)
         self.DeptName = ko.observable(data.DeptName)
       }

       DepartmentViewModel = new DepartmentDetailsViewModel();
       $(".Department-view").each(function () {
         ko.applyBindings(DepartmentViewModel, $(this).get(0));
       });
```

Its a duplicate question as we were not able to fix it. Please help
[How to carry the data from one viewModel to another ViewModel Knockout JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179984/how-to-carry-the-data-from-one-viewmodel-to-another-viewmodel-knockout-js%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there are many typos and wrong bindings in your view that need your attention. Example :

```
<ul>
  <li foreach:EmployeeData>  // There is no data-bind="
    <div databind:"click:GetDepartmentDetails">   //databind => data-bind and You need = not : <div data-bind="click:$parent.GetDepartmentDetails">
        <span data-bind:"text:EmployeeId"> <span> // You need = not : 
        <span data-bind:"text:EmployeeName"> <span>
        <span data-bind:"text:EmployeeImage"> <span>
     <div> 
   <li>
<ul>
```

You can define an observable variable in your employeeViewModel to hold a new instance of DepartmentViewModel and then you can call any functions through that variable and there is no need to re-apply `ko` many times.

Below I am trying to use your code by using a fake data to show you how you can approach this. 
Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/157/

**View:**

```
<h1>Employee View</h1>
<div class="Employee-view"  data-role="view" id="employee">
  <div data-role="content" >
    <ul>
      <li data-bind="foreach:EmployeeData">
        <div data-bind="click:$parent.GetDepartmentDetails">
          <span data-bind="text:EmployeeId"> </span>
          <span data-bind="text:EmployeeName"> </span>
          <span data-bind="text:EmployeeImage"> </span>
        </div> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>Department View</h1>
<div data-bind="with:DepartmentVM">
  <div class="Department-view" data-role="view" id="Department">
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul>
        <li   data-bind = "foreach:DepartmentData ">
          <div>
            <span data-bind = "text:DeptId"> </span>
            <span data-bind = "text:DeptName"> </span>
          </div> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Models :**

```
function EmployeeViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  // Here you define an observable variable to hold your DepartmentVM 
  self.DepartmentVM = ko.observable();
  self.EmployeeData = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.GetEmployee = function(UserName,Password){  
    var UserModel = { UserName: UserName, Password: Password}
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       url: serverUrl + 'xxx/xxx/GetEmployee',
       data: UserModel,
       success: function (data) {
         self.EmployeeData($.map(data, function (item) {
           return new EmployeeModel(item);
         }))
       }
    });
  }

  //Here I am calling GetEmployee()
  self.GetEmployee();

  // Below you have a knockout function
  self.GetDepartmentDetails = function (EmployeeData){
    console.log(EmployeeData)
    // Create a new instance of your DepartmentViewModel and then you can call the fucntion inside of it and pass your data
    self.DepartmentVM(new DepartmentViewModel());
    self.DepartmentVM().GetEmployeeByDepartment(EmployeeData);
  }
}
function DepartmentViewModel () {
  var self = this;
  self.DepartmentData = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.GetEmployeeByDepartment = function(item){  
    //Below you need ()  to get the value of observable variable item.EmployeeId()
    employeeID = item.EmployeeId()
    employeename = item.EmployeeName()  

     var DeptModel = { Employeename: employeeID, Employeename: employeename}
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       url: serverUrl + 'xxx/xxx/GetDepratmenDetails',
       data: DeptModel ,
       success: function (data) {
          self.DepartmentData ($.map(data, function (item) {
             return new DepartmentModel(item);
           }))
       }
    });
  }
}

function DepartmentModel(data)
{
  var self = this;
  self.DeptId = ko.observable(data.DeptID)
  self.DeptName = ko.observable(data.DeptName)
}
function EmployeeModel(data)
{
  var self = this;
  self.EmployeeId = ko.observable(data.EmployeeId)
  self.EmployeeName = ko.observable(data.EmployeeName)
  self.EmployeeImage = ko.observable(data.EmployeeImage)
}
var EmployeeVM = new EmployeeViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(EmployeeVM);
```

Comment: Matt, we were struggling for a long time. You solved it. Thanks for taking time and explaining us so clearly.  You are awesome :) :) :)